# How to prevent Opera Mini from forcibly scaling down an `<img>`?

Tags: html, css, image, opera-mini

I'm trying to size an `<img>` tag so it'll always fit the whole screen *width*. Something similar to the below does it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>testbed</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #a-container {
                width: 100%;
                background: lime;
            }

            #an-image {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: none !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="a-container">
            <img id="an-image" src="http://.../some-really-big-image.jpg" alt="an image">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Except in Opera Mini, that is. Other browsers show no green, but Opera Mini does something weird with `#an-image` such that the green background from `#a-container` appears on the right side, even though `#an-image`'s width is *never* larger than the viewport's. Even setting `max-width: none` isn't helping.

Without the CSS, Opera Mini will scale down `#an-image` to fit anyway.

<s>Seems like Opera Mini is factoring in some padding in the viewport when resizing the image, even though I've removed it from both `<html>` and `<body>`.</s> Am I missing something here? Even better: **is there a way to entirely override/disable this image-resizing behavior of Opera Mini?**

One more thing: I did test using `background-image` and `background-size: contain`; while it *does* work, **I need the image to reside in an `<img>` tag**.

**UPDATE**: I did some more research on this and it seems the aforementioned "weird" thing Opera Mini does to `#an-image` is that it **scales the image down to 95% of the viewport width if larger than that**, while keeping its aspect ratio. The question of whether this behavior can be overridden still remains, though.

Comment: `width: 100vw` will do it.

Comment: Nope, no support yet :(

Comment: Make it as Data URI for opera mini